# How would I search and replace multiple regexes using python re

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python replace multiple strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/python-replace-multiple-strings)

I am looking to replace `“ “`, `“\r”`, `“\n”`, `“<”`, `“>”`, `“’”` (single quote), and `‘”’` (double quote) with `“”` (empty). I’m also looking to replace `“;”` and `“|”` with `“,”`.

Would this be handled by `re.search` since I want to be able to search anywhere in the text, or would I use `re.sub`.

What would be the best way to handle this? I have found bits and pieces, but not where multiple regexes are handled.

Comment: If you are replacing one constant string with another, there's no need to use regular expressions.

Comment: Did you copy / paste those quotes from somewhere or did you actually get matching quotes typing into the text box in the browser?

Comment: copy and paste of course

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to replace only single characters then you could use [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
import string

table = string.maketrans(';|', ',,')
deletechars = ' \r\n<>\'"'

print "ex'a;m|ple\n".translate(table, deletechars)
# -> exa,m,ple
```

Comment: ooooh yes ! that's what to do !

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove all occurrences of those characters, just put them all in a character class and do [`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
your_str = re.sub(r'[ \r\n\'"]+', '', your_str)
your_str = re.sub(r'[;|]', ',', your_str)
```

You have to call `re.sub()` for every replacement rule.

Comment: so your_str would be an instance of the character class ? not sure what you mean by that "put them all in a character class

Comment: Read [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for more info. This is elementary regex stuff.

Comment: +1 for having thought to place '+' after the brackets (I had forgot)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

reg = re.compile('([ \r\n\'"]+)|([;|]+)')

ss = 'bo ba\rbu\nbe\'bi"by-ja;ju|jo'

def repl(mat, di = {1:'',2:','}):
    return di[mat.lastindex]

print reg.sub(repl,ss)
```

Note: '|' loses its speciality between brackets