# How to escape $ on Python string Template class?

Tags: python, string, try-catch

#### Introduction

The string module has a Template class, that lets you make substitutions in a string using a mapping object, for instance:

```
>>> string.Template('var is $var').substitute({'var': 1})
'var is 1'
```

The substitute method may raise a KeyError exception, if an attempt is made to substitute an element that is missing from the mapping, for instance

```
>>> string.Template('var is $var and foo is $foo').substitute({'var': 1})
KeyError: 'foo'
```

or may raise a ValueError, if the template string is invalid, e.g. it contains a `$` character followed by a space:

```
>>> string.Template('$ var is $var').substitute({'var': 1})
ValueError: Invalid placeholder in string: line 1, col 1
```

#### The Problem

Given a template string and a mapping, I want to determine whether all place-holders in the template would be substituted. For this, I would try to make the substitution and catch any KeyError exception:

```
def check_substitution(template, mapping):
    try:
        string.Template(template).substitute(mapping)
    except KeyError:
        return False
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return True
```

But this doesn't work, because if the template is invalid and a ValueError is raised, subsequent KeyErrors aren't caught:

```
>>> check_substitution('var is $var and foo is $foo', {'var': 1})
False
>>> check_substitution('$ var is $var and foo is $foo', {'var': 1})
True
```

but I *don't care* about ValueErrors. So, what would be the right approach to this problem?

Comment: Templates have a `safe_substitute` method that ignores any ValueError and goes on to make the substitutions. The problem is it also ignores KeyErrors.

Comment: The possible `ValueError` cases are all related to illegal uses of the `$` character, right? So why not do a bit of preprocessing of the string to escape illegal uses of `$`?

Comment: @PedroRomano This could work, but would require figuring out all cases that trigger a `ValueError`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The docs say](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/string#template-strings) that you can replace the pattern as long as it contains all necessary named groups:

```
import re
from string import Template


class TemplateIgnoreInvalid(Template):
    # override pattern to make sure `invalid` never matches
    pattern = r"""
    %(delim)s(?:
      (?P<escaped>%(delim)s) |   # Escape sequence of two delimiters
      (?P<named>%(id)s)      |   # delimiter and a Python identifier
      {(?P<braced>%(id)s)}   |   # delimiter and a braced identifier
      (?P<invalid>^$)            # never matches (the regex is not multilined)
    )
    """ % dict(delim=re.escape(Template.delimiter), id=Template.idpattern)


def check_substitution(template, **mapping):
    try:
        TemplateIgnoreInvalid(template).substitute(mapping)
    except KeyError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

#### Tests

```
f = check_substitution
assert f('var is $var', var=1)
assert f('$ var is $var', var=1)
assert     f('var is $var and foo is $foo', var=1, foo=2)
assert not f('var is $var and foo is $foo', var=1)
assert     f('$ var is $var and foo is $foo', var=1, foo=2)
assert not f('$ var is $var and foo is $foo', var=1)
# support all invalid patterns
assert f('var is $var and foo is ${foo', var=1)
assert f('var is $var and foo is ${foo', var=1, foo=2) #NOTE: problematic API
assert     f('var is $var and foo is ${foo and ${baz}', var=1, baz=3)
assert not f('var is $var and foo is ${foo and ${baz}', var=1)
```

It works for all invalid occurences of the delimiter (`$`).

The examples show that ignoring invalid patterns conceals simple typos in the template so it is not a good API.

Comment: Perfect! I'll have to think about what you say that it's a bad idea to support invalid patterns. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This is a Quick Fix (Using recursion):

```
def check_substitution(tem, m):
    try:
        string.Template(tem).substitute(m)
    except KeyError:
        return False
    except ValueError:
        return check_substitution(tem.replace('$ ', '$'), m) #strip spaces after $
    return True
```

I Know its take a longer time if there is more than One Space between `$` and `var` , so you may improve it by using Regular Expression.

**EDIT**

escaping `$` into `$$` makes more sense [ Thanks @Pedro ] so you can catch `ValueError` by this statement:

```
return check_substitution(tem.replace('$ ', '$$ '), m) #escaping $ by $$
```

Comment: This solution is not generic. It still fails if the character after the space is not a letter and assumes that the space after the `$` is spurious and the original intention was a placeholder composed of the `$` and the word after the space. Escaping the lone `$` by doubling it would make more sense.

Comment: @Dantario Thanks. The escaping would require more work, though. For example, the template `${foo` also triggers a ValueError, because of the unbalanced `{`... that's why I wanted to avoid parsing the template myself, but maybe there's no alternative.

Comment: @ErnestA: [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12769116/4279) fixes `${foo` issue.

Answer (score -1):

Python will not do string substitution over multiple lines

If you have this string

```
criterion = """
    <criteria>
    <order>{order}</order>
      <body><![CDATA[{code}]]></body>
    </criteria>
"""

criterion.format(dict(order="1",code="Hello")
```

results in:

```
KeyError: 'order'
```

A solution is to use the string.Template module

```
from string import Template

criterion = """
    <criteria>
    <order>$order</order>
      <body><![CDATA[$code]]></body>
    </criteria>
"""

Template(criterion).substitute(dict(order="1",code="hello")
```

NOTE: you have to prefix the keywords with a $ not wrap them in {}

output is:

```
 <criteria>
    <order>1</order>
      <body><![CDATA[hello]]></body>
    </criteria>
```

Full docs are: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings

Comment: "Python will not do string substitution over multiple lines" - Wrong. Use `criterion.format(**dict(order="1", code="Hello")` or just `criterion.format(order="1", code="Hello")`