# Replace multiple strings in csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to replace multiple strings in a csv file. There is no specific column these strings may be in.

I used the example in this thread [Python replace multiple strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/python-replace-multiple-strings), the wordpress entry. I thought I had it with the CSV module but I guess that does not have a replace function. I tried the below, but it only does the replace from the first dictionary. It has to do the entries in the first dictionary first, the order of the second dictionary doesn't matter as much.

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

f_dic = {'-':' '}
s_dic = {'  ':' ','   ':' ','SASD D':'SASD-D','DC W':'DC-W',r'PROD\s\d':r'PROD\d'}

with open('file1.csv','r') as f:
    text=f.read()
    with open('file2.csv','w') as w:
        text=replace_all(text,f_dic)
        text=replace_all(text,s_dic)
        w.write(text)
```

Can someone help me with this? or even better a csv module version of this?

Thanks,
B0T

*EDIT*

This is my final code after the answer. It worked.

```
import re

def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

f_dic = {'-':' '}
s_dic = {'  ':' ','   ':' ','SASD D':'SASD-D','DC W':'DC-W'}
t_dic = {'  ':' '}

with open('file1.csv','r') as f:
    text=f.read()
    text=replace_all(text,f_dic)
    text=replace_all(text,s_dic)
    text=replace_all(text,t_dic)
    text=re.sub(r'PROD\s(?=[1-9])',r'PROD',text)

with open('file2.csv','w') as w:
    w.write(text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... this worked fine for me.

I'm running python 2.7.3

try a minimal test case starting with file1.csv containing "123abc":

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

f_dic = {'a':'d'}
s_dic = {'1':'x'}

with open('file1.csv','r') as f:
    text=f.read()
    with open('file2.csv','w') as w:
        text=replace_all(text,f_dic)
        text=replace_all(text,s_dic)
        print text
        w.write(text)
```

After running, file2.csv contained x23dbc

Perhaps my test case was too simple. How about you give us what you had in file1.csv, what you expected to see in file2.csv and what you actually saw in file2.csv.

Comment: Actually, it looks like everything worked except for the '  ':' ' and the regex replace r'PROD\s\d':r'PROD\d'. Weird. I am using 2.7.5

Comment: Not sure what you mean, are you saying that your original case worked, except the space replacement seems off? Can you give your input, expected output and actual output?

Comment: Well, it's a large file. An example of a string I want to change and is not changing is: "DRE  United States PROD 2". I want to get rid of the extra spaces after the first word, and make "PROD 2" "PROD2".

Comment: Note: In the above there is supposed to be two spaces after "DRE".

Comment: Well according to your original rules, `"DRE  "` should become `"DRE "`, and `"PROD 2"` would not change

Comment: Ohh, I thought I tested that regex, I must be tireder than I thought. I'm going to try this r'PROD\s(?=[1-9])':r'PROD'. You said the double space should be replaced by the single space in the original code? Thanks, BTW.

Comment: the replace method on a string will NOT do regular expressions. the `r` on the front of the string just signifies it is a raw string literal, more on that here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-rstring-flags-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-litte

Comment: I would use the regular expression module if I were you :http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

Comment: Also, I added a third dictionary with {'  ',' '} and this time it got rid of all the double spaces.

Comment: when I run above code I get following error:

 > for i, j in replacements.iteritems():
 > AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'iteritems'