# Replacing based on multiple conditionals and lists in python

Tags: string, python-3.x, replace, conditional-statements

I'm a complete noob, so I hope this question isn't useless, but I can't find information anywhere.

I am working on what amounts to cleaning a bunch of data from an excel sheet, to get it into a working format. I need to take a long string and replace pretty much every word with something else.

For instance:
January must be replaced by a J, February with an F, etc. (I believe I can do this like this: [Python replace multiple strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/python-replace-multiple-strings))

Each word in parentheses must be replaced with an integer in parentheses, starting with (1), but making sure any given word is always replaced with the same integer.

Every word not containing numbers must be deleted, unless it is followed by a four-digit number.

The list goes on...

Basically I just need a replace argument that will take more complicated instructions than "replace variable with other variable." I've tried tinkering with replace itself, but it doesn't seem to take any arguments like these.

PS I'm using python 3.3

Comment: why not just call replace multiple times, assigning the results to new strings?

Comment: That will work just fine for the replacing January with February, for instance. If I start specifying all of the words not containing numbers, I'll have to list at least several hundred of them.

Comment: Maybe I should just create a list by splitting at every whitespace and then append each element to a new list based on conditionals?

Comment: In that case, take a look at regexes and the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module - you're going to need it.

Comment: yes, that could also work

Comment: Thanks for the prod in the right direction.

Comment: You can replace quite everything you want with str.replace. You can even `yourstring.replace('this', 'that').replace('those', 'these')` as your string is an object. Splitting might also be a good idea if you have a constant number of whitespace. I would advice you to convert your excel document to csv so you can use the csv lib. (Or any excel lib anyway) I prefer CSV because you can treat it even without the csv lib. Because of it's separators, you can split every line to a list.