# logic for String replacement in python

Tags: python, string

How to replace a string in python
For example
If the text is 'new words are newest n ew' and i want to replace 'new' word with 'y'
If I use string.replace command
The above text will change to
'y words are yest n ew'
I don't want this to happen
Ideally it should be
'y words are newest y'
Could some body throw some light on how to achieve this using python.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? The [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) lists string functions.

Comment: I dont see other option for string replacement in the [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

Comment: search for `replace`, hint it's at the bottom of the page

Comment: The other option i can go for is to use a dictionary. And make a exhaustive list of all the cases. But that doesnt seem to be an effective way.

Comment: So there is a special rule for "n ew". Are there any other special rules? You need to specify _exactly_ what is needed

Comment: `string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])`
Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.

Comment: The text i mentioned is just an example. The replacement should happen only for the word that i needed. Here the word is 'new'

Comment: True!You can use dictionary! check this thread but you need to distinguish between different cases http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/python-replace-multiple-strings

Comment: 'n ew' is also equivalent to 'new', ofcourse it has space between words. But i dont want 'newest' to be changed because it is a different word from 'new'

Comment: hi [scrappedcola](http://stackoverflow.com/users/462006/scrappedcola). I have already used the replace command and posted the result also in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = 'new words are newest n ew'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\bn\s*e\s*w\b', 'y', s)
'y words are newest y'
```

`'\bn\s*e\s*w\b'` is a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

`\b` means a word break
`n`, `e`, `w` mean the letter "n", "e", "w" respectively
`\s*` means zero or more whitespace characters

The regex given here may not be exactly what you need. You need to describe the rules exactly if you need a more (or less) restrictive regex.

Comment: This is not very helpful for someone who wanna understand things! without explaining the code, regular expression is an advanced topic.

Comment: Hi gnibbler. Thanks for your answer. But i am not familiar with the 're' module. I will go through it

Comment: @user3378649, looking forward to see your answer using a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with regular expressions (although i suggest you do because they are so powerful) because they're hard to grasp, you could try something like the following:

Create a `list` with every word of your `string` and then iterate through the `list` and replace every word if it matches the `string` 'new'. Then print the `list` as a `string` (or you may assing it to a new/old variable the same way)

```
wordy = 'new words are newest n ew'
wordy_list = wordy.split()
for i, x in enumerate(wordy_list):
    if x == 'new':
        wordy_list[i] = 'y'
print(' '.join(wordy_list))
```

You could also write a one line lambda function which does the same thing like the following:

```
wordy = 'new words are newest n ew'
new_replace = lambda x: x if x != 'new' else 'y'
print(' '.join([new_replace(x) for x in wordy.split()]))
```