# python replace multiple words retaining case

Tags: python, regex, django, str-replace

I'm trying to write a filter in django that highlights words based on a search query. For example, if my string contains `this is a sample string that I want to highlight using my filter` and my search stubs are `sam` and `ring`, my desired output would be:

```
this is a <mark>sam</mark>ple st<mark>ring</mark> that I want to highlight using my filter
```

I'm using the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/python-replace-multiple-strings) to replace multiple words. I've presented the code below:

```
import re

words = search_stubs.split()
rep = dict((re.escape(k), '<mark>%s</mark>'%(k)) for k in words)
pattern = re.compile('|'.join(rep.keys()))
text = pattern.sub(lambda m : rep[re.escape(m.group(0))], text_to_replace)
```

However, when there is case sensitivity, this breaks. For example, if I have the string `Check highlight function`, and my search stub contains `check`, this breaks.

The desired output in this case would naturally be:

```
<mark>Check</mark> highlight function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go for dictionary here. `(?i)` called case-insensitive modifier helps to do a case-insensitive match.

```
>>> s = "this is a sample string that I want to highlight using my filter"
>>> l = ['sam', 'ring']
>>> re.sub('(?i)(' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, l)) + ')', r'<mark>\1</mark>', s)
'this is a <mark>sam</mark>ple st<mark>ring</mark> that I want to highlight using my filter'
```

EXample 2:

```
>>> s = 'Check highlight function'
>>> l = ['check']
>>> re.sub('(?i)(' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, l)) + ')', r'<mark>\1</mark>', s)
'<mark>Check</mark> highlight function'
```

Answer (score 1):

The *simple* way to do this is to not try to build a dict mapping every single word to its marked-up equivalent, and just use a capturing group and a reference to it. Then you can just use the `IGNORECASE` flag to do a case-insensitive search.

```
pattern = re.compile('({})'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, words))),
                     re.IGNORECASE)
text = pattern.sub(r'<mark>\1</mark>', text_to_replace)
```

For example, if `text_to_replace` were:

```
I am Sam. Sam I am. I will not eat green eggs and spam.
```

… then `text` will be:

```
I am <mark>Sam</mark>. <mark>Sam</mark> I am. I will not eat green eggs and spam
```

---

If you really *did* want to do it your way, you could. For example:

```
text = pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))].replace(m, m.group(0)),
                   text_to_replace)
```

But that would be kind of silly. You're building a dict with `'sam'` embedded in the value, just so you can replace that `'sam'` with the `'Sam`' that you actually matched.

---

See [Grouping](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping) in the Regular Expression HOWTO for more on groups and references, and the [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) docs for specifics on using references in substitutions.