# Python regex for quickly removing any possible instances of substrings?

Tags: python, regex, string, algorithm

Given some string:

```
"this is a test string ababababa"
```

And some "stop" words to remove:

```
"rin" "hi" "tri" "ababa"
```

The resulting string becomes

```
"ts is a test sg "
```

So I basically want to do the equivalent of the following (efficiently with a regex):

1. For each stop word, slide it across the main string, one character at a time. Any time there's a pattern match, I "mark" the corresponding letters for removal later.
2. After all stop words have been processed, remove any letters from the main string that are marked.

Comment: Made into regex question instead

Comment: Check the functionality of re.findall, it comes close, but may not be what you describe w.r.t. overlapping matches

Comment: The overlapping matches is the main reason I made the question (I had already tried re.findall although unsuccessfully)

Comment: I'm not sure there's any reasonable way to do this except "by hand" (i.e. using the `pos` argument to [`match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match)).

Comment: @Kevin Can this code be modified to do overlapping? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6117124/5231588

Comment: @user262329: Not easily.  `sub()` finds non-overlapping matches.  You would have to totally re-implement it.

Comment: I had looked up the flags for sub() and couldn't find anything either, darn.

Comment: That sounds more complicated than just calling `match()` in a loop with progressively larger `pos` values (or doing repeated string slicing, but YMMV on performance in that case).  If you figure out a DFA/NFA solution, be sure to answer your question with it, so the rest of us can read about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have

```
orig_str = 'this is a test string ababababa'
stopwords = ['rin', 'hi', 'tri', 'ababa']
```

I think this should do what you want. The main trick is to use the non-consuming matching syntax [`(?=...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to find all the overlapping matches:

```
# Update: sort stop words so that words prefixing 
# other stop words don't cause issues
stopwords.sort(key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True)
pattern = re.compile('|'.join('(?=(%s))' % word for word in stopwords))
matches = pattern.finditer(orig_str)
```

Once you have the matches, you can do something like this to remove matching characters.  Not sure it's the most efficient, but it works:

```
mask = [True] * len(orig_str) # True means keep this char
for match in matches:
    # mark all matches' positions in the mask
    wordlen = max(len(word) for word in match.groups() if word)
    mask[match.start():match.start()+wordlen] = [False] * wordlen

new_str = "".join(c for (c,i) in zip(orig_str, mask) if i)
# new_str:
# 'ts is a test sg '
```

Comment: Damn, I forgot about lookahead.  Yeah, this is probably the right solution.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work in all overlap cases. Try orig_str = "fullword" with stopwords ["full","fullword"] -- it only removes "full" when it should be removing the whole thing. It seems like the order of the stopwords matters (whereas ideally it shouldn't)

Comment: Ah yes, good point.  Issue is when one stop word is a prefix of another, the `|` will always match the first and then short circuit. I worked around this by sorting the stopwords by length, so that the earlier precondition in the pattern are always longer or equal length.  Updated answer