# hylang replace multiple words

Tags: string, replace, hy

I would like to perform multiple replace operations on a string, in *hylang*

Given that *hy* is very similar to *python* i found a related solution on [Python replace multiple strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978)

```
# python
def replace(s, repls):
   reduce(lambda a, kv: a.replace(*kv), repls, s)
replace("hello, world", [["hello", "goodbye"],["world", "earth"]])
> 'goodbye, earth'
```

so i tried to port it to *hy*:

```
;hy
(defn replace [s repls]
    (reduce (fn [a kv] (.replace a kv)) repls s))
(replace "hello, world", [["hello" "bye"] ["earth" "moon"]])
> TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

this fails, as the `kv` argument to the lambda-function in `reduce` is interpreted as single arg (e.g. `["hello" "bye"]`) instead of two args `"hello"` &  `"bye"`.

In python i can use the `*`-operator to dereference the list to arguments, but it seems i cannot do that in hy.

```
(defn replace [s repls]
    (reduce (fn [a kv] (.replace a *kv)) repls s))
> NameError: global name '*kv' is not defined
```

Is there an elegant way to

- expand lists as arguments
- **AND/OR** to replace multiple words in a string

in `hy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the trick seems to be to use `(apply)`

```
(defn replace-words
      [s repls]
      (reduce (fn [a kv] (apply a.replace kv)) repls s))
(replace-words "hello, world" (, (, "hello" "goodbye") (, "world" "blue sky")))
```