# How to replace characters in python with Regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have been tring to replace german letters into English way of writing:

```
Ä -> Ae
Ü -> Ue
ß -> ss
```

I tried this way:

```
re.sub("ö","oe",wordLineElements)
re.sub("Ö","Oe",wordLineElements)
re.sub("ä","ae",wordLineElements)
re.sub("Ä","Ae",wordLineElements)
re.sub("ü","ue",wordLineElements)
re.sub("Ü","Ue",wordLineElements)
re.sub("ß","ss",wordLineElements)
```

but looks like it does not work, so I need to do it with one `re.sub()`

what is the regex way of doing it?

and if it's ok, what is a general way of using regex?

Comment: Use a simple `s = s.replace("x", "Yy").replace(...,...)...`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
I Could do that of course, but I though to develop my knowlage, I would like to see how to change it in regex way, so I could use it in the future

Comment: `re.sub` returns a new string with the replacement.  So you need something like `wordLineElements = re.sub("ö","oe",wordLineElements)`.  There is also a great answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/python-replace-multiple-strings) that does multiple replacements with some clever code.

Comment: @GWW I would argue that your comment makes for a good answer.

Comment: There is no knowledge to gain in using regexp for such case. The best answer is by @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @Ramon

I would also agree that his answer is as good enough as needed to make the code works. but I still would like to have it in Regex. I looked though in the Internet, but it was not clear enough, this why I asked here, so I could learn by example 

thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have already got the solution, but here's it if you want to do with regex `re` module:

```
>>> sub_dict = {
                u"ö": "oe",
                u"Ö": "Oe",
                u"ä": "ae",
                u"Ä": "Ae",
                u"ü": "ue",
                u"Ü": "Ue",
                u"ß": "ss"
               }
>>> sub_regex = re.compile("(%s)"%"|".join([german_letter.decode('UTF-8') for german_letter in sub_dict.iterkeys()]))
>>> sub_regex.sub(lambda x: sub_dict[x.group(0)], u'asdasdsüadsadas')
102: u'asdasdsueadsadas'
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need regular expressions, [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) would be a better choice:

```
d = {
    "ö": "oe",
    "Ö": "Oe",
    "ä": "ae",
    "Ä": "Ae",
    "ü": "ue",
    "Ü": "Ue",
    "ß": "ss"
}

s = "Ä test ß test Ü"
print(s.translate({ord(k): v for k, v in d.items()}))
```

Prints:

```
Ae test ss test Ue
```

Comment: Nice way of doing it.. thank you

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that re.sub doesn't modify the string in place, it returns a new string. Try:

```
wordLineElements = re.sub("ö","oe",wordLineElements)
wordLineElements = re.sub("Ö","Oe",wordLineElements)
wordLineElements = re.sub("ä","ae",wordLineElements)
wordLineElements = re.sub("Ä","Ae",wordLineElements)
wordLineElements = re.sub("ü","ue",wordLineElements)
wordLineElements = re.sub("Ü","Ue",wordLineElements)
wordLineElements = re.sub("ß","ss",wordLineElements)
```

Answer (score 2):

`re.sub` returns a new string with the replacement. So you need something like `wordLineElements = re.sub("ö","oe",wordLineElements)`. There is also a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/python-replace-multiple-strings) that does multiple replacements with some clever code