# How to match the first word in a string?

Tags: python, string

I want to match the word `'St'` or `'St.'` or `'st'` or `'st.'` BUT only as the first word of a string.
For example `'St. Mary Church Church St.'` - should find ONLY first `'St.'`.

- `'st. Mary Church Church St.'` - should find ONLY `'st.'`
- `'st Mary Church Church St.'` - should find ONLY `'st'`

I want to eventually replace the first occurrence with 'Saint'.

Comment: Why do you need a regex? Just split the string up into words by whitespace and get the first one.

Comment: Does the code only have to handle strings that start with a variation of "St."? Or are there other strings that start with something else?

Answer (score 3):

Regex [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) allows you to define the number of occurrences to replace in a string:

```
import re

s = "St. Mary Church Church St."
new_s = re.sub(r'^(St.|st.|St|st)\s', r'Saint ', s, 1) # the last argument defines the number of occurrences to be replaced. In this case, it will replace the first occurrence only.
print(new_s)
#  'Saint Mary Church Church St.'
```

Comment: This nearly works, but it needs one small fix; if you substitute strings starting with "St" or "st", there is no space after "Saint", so `re.sub(…)`ing `s = "St Mary Church Church St."` gives 'SaintMary Church Church St.'

Comment: Thanks pointed it out. But like you've seen in the example, the output was good. Anyway, I edited my answer to take care the "st" expression followed by a space and added a space after "Saint". Thank you. ; )

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a regex for this, just use the [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method on your string to split it by whitespace. This will return a list of every word in your string:

```
matches = ["St", "St.", "st", "st."]
name = "St. Mary Church Church St."

words = name.split()  # split the string into words into a list
if words [0] in matches:
    words[0] = "Saint"  # replace the first word in the list (St.) with Saint
new_name = " ".join(words)  # create the new name from the words, separated by spaces
print(new_name)  # Output: "Saint Mary Church Church St."
```

Comment: That's nice, but it doesn't check if the first word is St, or .. etc.

Comment: OP isn't supplying enough information whether there are strings that don't start with a variation of "St."... I'll update my answer though.

Comment: the [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.split#str.split) method accepts a maxsplit argument. it could be nice to provide it to avoid processing all the string after it found the first split.

Comment: @Tryph, that's quite useful, although it doesn't really simplify the current code. Besides, there is basically no processing of the rest of the string, only when `join`ing the words again.

Comment: It is possible to remove the need of `matches` by doing `if words[0].lower().strip('.') == 'st':`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the `flag` parameter into the `sub` function. This will allow you to reduce the amount of information you need to pass to the `pattern` parameter in the tool. This makes the code a little cleaner and reduces the chances of you missing a pattern:

```
import re

s = "St. Mary Church Church St."
new_s = re.sub(r'^(st.|st)\s', r'Saint ', s, 1, flags=re.IGNORECASE) # You can shorten the code from above slightly by ignoring the case
print(new_s)
#  'Saint Mary Church Church St.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the regex `'^\S+'` to match the first non-space character in your string.

```
import re 

s = 'st Mary Church Church St.'
m = re.match(r'^\S+', s)
m.group()    # 'st'

s = 'st. Mary Church Church St.'
m = re.match(r'^\S+', s)
m.group()    # 'st.'
```

Comment: @orz, it may be your first time, so your answer has been edited to show what might be expected next time, format-wise.  Remember to format code with code blocks, use reproducible examples that run in console and briefly explain what is happening.  And welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

[Python 3.10 introduced a new Structural Pattern Matching feature](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching) (otherwise known as `match/case`) which can fit this use-case:

```py
s = "St. Mary Church Church St."

words = s.split()
match words:
    case ["St" | "St." | "st" | "st.", *rest]:
        print("Found st at the start")
        words[0] = "Saint"
    case _:
        print("didn't find st at the start")

print(' '.join(words))
```

Will give:

```
Found st at the start
Saint Mary Church Church St.
```

While using `s = "Mary Church Church St."` will give:

```
didn't find st at the start
Mary Church Church St.
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import re

string = "Some text"

replace = {'St': 'Saint', 'St.': 'Saint', 'st': 'Saint', 'st.': 'Saint'}
replace = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in replace.iteritems())
pattern = re.compile("|".join(replace.keys()))
for text in string.split():
    text = pattern.sub(lambda m: replace[re.escape(m.group(0))], text)
```

This should work I guess, please check.
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/python-replace-multiple-strings)

Comment: This doesn't work, it doesn't replace anything, it just seems to remove the first word from `string`