# Python multiple replacement with matching

Tags: python-2.x

Work in Progress Json2yaml converter for Ansible (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_group_module.html) creation

Link to Project:
https://github.com/shdobxr/json2yamlAnsible/blob/master/json2yaml.py

#### Answered! See above for project.

I have been researching this on stack. And it's just not clicking.

[Python replace multiple strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/python-replace-multiple-strings)

Here is my attempt, please be kind I have dabbled with python in the past. The rust is showing here:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import re, sys, json, yaml

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
#   print yaml.safe_dump(json.load(f), default_flow_style=False)
   a = yaml.safe_dump(json.load(f), default_flow_style=False)

c = sys.argv[1] + ".yml"

text_file = open(c, "w")
text_file.write(a)
text_file.close

replacements = {
    '    ToPort:': '            to_port:',
    '  - FromPort:': '            from_port:',
    'UserIdGroupPairs:': '',
    'Vpc:': '',
    'VpcPeeringConnectionId:': '',
    'UserIdGroupPairs:': '',
    'PrefixListIds: []': '',
    '- Description:': '        description:',
    '  GroupName:': '    - name:',
    '  -     IpProtocol:': '          - proto:',
    '- Description:': '        description:',
    'SecurityGroups:': '- name:',
    '  IpPermissions:': '        rules:',
    '  IpPermissionsEgress:': '        rules_egress:',
    '  GroupId:': '',
    '    - GroupId:': '            group_id:'
}


replacements = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in replacements.iteritems())
#pattern = re.compile('|'.join(replacements.keys()))

remove_pattern = re.compile('|'.join(k for k, v in replacements.iteritems() if v is None))
replace_pattern = re.compile('|'.join(k for k, v in replacements.iteritems() if v is not None))


def rewrite(text):
    if remove_pattern.search(text):
        return ''
    return replace_pattern.sub(lambda m: replacements[re.escape(m.group())], text)


with open(c, 'rt') as fin:
    with open('out.txt', 'wt') as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(rewrite(line))
```

Test file (save this as test.json)

```
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 22,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "10.0.0.0/24"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 22,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "UserId": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                            "GroupId": "sg-xxxxxxxx"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 3389,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "10.0.0.0/24"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 3389,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "UserId": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                            "GroupId": "sg-xxxxxxxx"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "Description": "TEST JSON",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "Test JSON",
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ],
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 22,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "10.0.0.0/24"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 22,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "UserId": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                            "GroupId": "sg-xxxxxxxx"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 3389,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "10.0.0.0/24"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 3389,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "UserId": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                            "GroupId": "sg-xxxxxxxx"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "GroupName": "Test JSON",
            "VpcId": "vpc-XXXXXXXX",
            "OwnerId": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "GroupId": "sg-xxxxxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth I am writing a json to yaml converter to make EC2 SG JSON output to Ansible Playbook a snap.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_group_module.html

Comment: Wouldn't something as simple as `line.replace('ToPort', 'to_port').replace('FromPort', 'from_port')` be sufficient for your case?

Comment: Let me give that a go. I wanted to use a dictionary to keep things neat. And to add more diversity to the matching. Thnx!

Comment: Wouldn't the dictionary need to be named something different than "replacements"? If so what changes would need to be made through the script?

Comment: That's just a variable, the name can be chosen freely (just replace all occurrences of it).

Comment: Understood, since I am using sysargs as the subject file, would the `def rewrite(text):` need to swap out "c" for "text"?

Comment: That name can also be chosen freely. One thing I see is the missing parenthesis in `text_file.close()`. You can likely skip creating the intermediate file completely and process the result of `yaml.safe_dump` directly. Could you please drop an example input file somewhere, so I can check what's happening?

Comment: example json posted in orig question area. Save that locally. As test.json thanks for the help!

Comment: Fixing the parentheses and ensuring that `remove_pattern` doesn't end up empty should be enough to make it work.

Comment: Merged your pull request. That got me over the bump. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you cited adapted for your use case:

```
import re

replacements = {
    'ToPort': 'to_port',
    'FromPort': None
}
replacements = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in replacements.iteritems())
remove_pattern = re.compile('|'.join(
                    k for k, v in replacements.iteritems() if v is None))
replace_pattern = re.compile('|'.join(
                    k for k, v in replacements.iteritems() if v is not None))


def rewrite(text):
    if remove_pattern.search(text):
        return ''
    return replace_pattern.sub(
                lambda m: replacements[re.escape(m.group())], text)


with open('in.txt', 'rt') as fin:
    with open('out.txt', 'wt') as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(rewrite(line))
```

Comment: Giving it a run right now. Yep precisely what I needed. Thanks for the assist.  For those that may be creating Ansible Playbooks for Security Group creation from json output I will update this comment with my github link. (if allowed)

Comment: https://github.com/shdobxr/json2yamlAnsible/blob/master/json2yaml.py Project link as promised.

Comment: `replacements = {
    'ToPort': 'to_port',
    'FromPort': <remove_line> 
}`
 <--- how would you remove the line entirely upon match

Comment: Updated the answer (a few lines longer, but still with a single `dict` to declare all changes).

Comment: `with open(c, 'rt') as fin:
    with open(c + ".out", 'wt') as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(rewrite(line))`

Getting Zerobyte out file