# Python, How to replace multiple parts (in a list) of elements in a list

Tags: python, list

A list of original strings:

```
Originals = ["nice apple", "orange", "pear sweet", "red ape"]
```

A list of strings to remove:

```
To_remove = ["nice ", " sweet"]
```

What I want to achieve is to remove the strings needed to be removed in each elements in the original words

```
result: ["apple", "orange", "pear", "red ape"]
```

I do following but it doesn’t produce a good result.

```
for t in To_remove:
    for o in Originals:
        print o.replace(t, "")
```

what would be the right way? Thank you.

Comment: *`but it doesn’t produce a good result`* -- **What do you see**? Please show us!

Comment: Your questions title is quite confusing, maybe you should reword it to match your actual need.

Comment: Suggestion for a catching title: **Howto "censor" a string list in python?** :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable. Hence, none of the methods you can call on a string does an in-place modification. They all return a new string, so you have to reassign the string returned by [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

```
for t in To_remove:
    for i in range(len(Originals)):
        Originals[i] = Originals[i].replace(t, "")
```

You can check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/python-replace-multiple-strings) for how to merge the replacement of multiple patterns.

Comment: And for just a tip and in case to use PEP8 standards: use snake case.

Comment: @Wencakisa see OP (concerning *`snake case`*)

Comment: *`the return value`* -- better use the *result of the replace operation* or something like this, to make clear **what** you mean.

Comment: @Wolf I added some clarification.

Comment: much better, though you provide a link to the docs of version 2, as I said: hard to google this ;)

Answer (score 3):

Because string is immutable, you have to reassign the list element.

```
for t in To_remove:
    for i, o in enumerate(Originals):
        Originals[i] = o.replace(t, "")

print Originals
```

hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the teaching. very good! hope you don't mind I choose the first answered for answer...

Comment: I like the *`print Originals`* idea, this part is missing in the OP

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the results of the replacement, but do not change the list contents. If you have a closer look on the [replace method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) (for *string*s(!)), you'll see that you are not only not changing the list but also not changing the strings you are getting `for o in Originals`. I omit including a working example, since [schwobaseggl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42020241/2932052) and [thangtn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42020223/2932052) <sup>[1]</sup> already provide it.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Who was really first? The SO timestamps contradict my personal experience.

Comment: BTW: the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) are very sparse, maybe this is the reason you have so bad Google results for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Originals = ["nice apple", "orange", "pear sweet", "red ape"]
To_remove = ["nice ", " sweet"]
result = []

for o in Originals:
    for t in To_remove:
        result.append(o.replace(t, ""))

print result
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Some more text may help to understand the purpose of the repetition of the already known.

Comment: ...I have to correct myself about this (concerning *'repetition'*) you don't an in-place replacement. A valid option.