# Python strip url and replace forward slash

Tags: python, python-2.7

I currently have a list of URLs

```
http://www.website.com/dynamic/download.ashx?id=123/12/12345
http://www.website.com/dynamic/download.ashx?id=12/121/123451
http://www.website.com/dynamic/download.ashx?id=1/1233/123
```

I am looking to create a new list replacing the / with _ and stripping the URL. Creating a new list:

```
123_12_12345
12_121_123451
1_1233_123
```

I have removed the URL by splitting

```
for z in columns['location']:
    print z.split('=')[1:]enter code here
    stripped.append(z.split('=')[1:])
```

help to replace / with _ would be appreciated.
cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python replace multiple strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/python-replace-multiple-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will split about =, grab the second part and then replace / with _.

```
urls = ["http://www.website.com/dynamic/download.ashx?id=123/12/12345",
        "http://www.website.com/dynamic/download.ashx?id=12/121/123451",
        "http://www.website.com/dynamic/download.ashx?id=1/1233/123"]

for url in urls:
    print(url.split("=")[1].replace("/","_"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newink = a.split('=')[0] + a.split('=')[1].replace('/','_')
```

Then loop for each link to convert it