# how to change multiple rows of csv file with corresponding dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, replace

**My csv file ("challenges.csv")** contains multiple rows as shown below (the number of columns are different, about 8000 rows):

2937 ,58462bc9a559fa7d29819028 ,29 ,57eb63d813fd7c0329bdb01f ,

2938 ,58462bc9a559fa7d29819028 ,30 ,57eb63d713fd7c0329bdafb5 ,57eb63d713fd7c0329bdafb6

---

And I also have 
**a dictionary named `mydic` from "forDic.csv"** for example:

```
{ '58462bc9a559fa7d29819028':'negative chin up', '57eb63d813fd7c0329bdb01f':'knee squeeze squat', '57eb63d713fd7c0329bdafb5: 'squat', '57eb63d713fd7c0329bdafb6':'lunge', ... }
```

I want to change values of `"challenges.csv"` with values of `mydic`
if values of `"challenges.csv"` is equal to keys of `mydic`. 
How can i do? Please help me.

---

**Expected output:**
a csv file which contains rows like below

2937 ,'negative chin up' ,29 ,'knee squeeze squat' ,

2938 ,'negative chin up' ,30 ,'squat' ,'lunge'

```
import csv

with open('./forDic.csv', mode='r')as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    mydic = dict((rows[0], rows[1]) for rows in reader)
    print(mydic)


def replace_all()
with open('./challenges.csv', mode='r')as infile, open('./challenges_new.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
    r = csv.reader(infile)
    w = csv.writer(outfile)

    for row in r:
        for k in iter(mydic.keys()):
        print(', '.join(row))
        rl = [w.replace(str(k), str(mydic.values())) for w in rl]
        print(rl[0])
        row_list_string = ' / '.join(map(str, rl))
        for k in list(mydic.keys()):
            k = k.replace(k, mydic.get(k))
            print(k)


replace_all()
```

Comment: can you paste data as text instead of image?

Comment: @saikumarm thanks!! 
this only a part of "challenges.csv"



224 ,5847aac3d22f9043ad999e64 ,27 ,

225 ,57b2fb7c50bc88cb7a168f40 ,1 ,57eb63d713fd7c0329bdafbd ,57eb63d813fd7c0329bdb019 ,57eb63d813fd7c0329bdb007 ,57eb63d813fd7c0329bdb043 ,57eb63d713fd7c0329bdaf62 ,57eb63d713fd7c0329bdaf63

Comment: Do you want to replace the csv text with the mapping you have in dict or you want to replace the complete row? Could you share your expected output as well

Comment: ㅑ want to replace the specific csv text with the mapping dictionary i have!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

### chanllenges.csv

```
317, change1, 89, change2, change3
318, change1, 89, change3, change4
```

### fordic.csv

```
change1, changedto1
change2, changedto2
change3, changedto3
change4, changedto4
```

The following code just prints the replaced line

```
import re, csv

with open('fordic.csv', mode='r')as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    mydic = dict((rows[0], rows[1]) for rows in reader)
    print(mydic)


mydic = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in mydic.iteritems())
pattern = re.compile("|".join(mydic.keys()))

with open('./challenges.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()

    for row in lines:
        print pattern.sub(lambda m: mydic[re.escape(m.group(0))], row)
```

### output

```
317,  changedto1, 89,  changedto2,  changedto3
318,  changedto1, 89,  changedto3,  changedto4
```

to understand the multi string replace follow this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/python-replace-multiple-strings)

Comment: Thanks but i got an error message...because i use python3.x? :
    mydic = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in mydic.iteritems())
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: pattern = re.compile("|".join(mydic.keys))
TypeError: can only join an iterable  T.T

Comment: there are changes in file names, please check the follow once, before you directly copy and test.

Comment: I changed file names, but still not solved.. anyway i really appreciate for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

It is best not to try and update the values in place, but rather create a new temporary file as output. This script attempts the dictionary substitution on all of your column values and writes each row back to the new temporary file. By using this approach the file can be of any size without needing to be loaded completely into memory:

The following approach should work:

```
import csv
import os

challenges = 'challenges.csv'
temp = '_temp.csv'

with open('forDic.csv', newline='') as f_fordic:
    mydic = {row[0] : row[1] for row in csv.reader(f_fordic)}

with open(challenges, newline='') as f_challenges, open(temp, 'w', newline='') as f_temp:
    csv_temp = csv.writer(f_temp)

    for row in csv.reader(f_challenges):
        csv_temp.writerow([mydic.get(c.strip(), c.strip()) for c in row])

# Rename the temp file back to challenges (optional)
os.remove(challenges)
os.rename(temp, challenges)
```

Giving you an updated `challenges.csv` file as follows:

```
2937,negative chin up,29,knee squeeze squat,
2938,negative chin up,30,squat,lunge
```