# String to phrase replacement python

Tags: python, regex, string, string-matching

I have a text string and I want to replace two words with a single word. E.g. if the word is `artificial intelligence`, I want to replace it with `artificial_intelligence`. This needs to be done for a list of 200 words and on a text file of size 5 mb.
I tried `string.replace` but it can work only for one element, not for the list.

Example

> Text='Artificial intelligence is useful for us in every situation of deep learning.'

```
List a : list b
Artificial intelligence: artificial_intelligence
Deep learning: deep_ learning 
...
```

`Text.replace('Artificial intelligence','Artificial_intelligence'`) is working.
But

```
For I in range(len(Lista)):
 Text=Text.replace(Lista[I],List b[I])
```

doesn't work.

Comment: 200 words doesn't look much, have you tried use Sublime Text and do a simple find / replace?

Comment: Actually I am having 98 such files..it will be too long to manually update all:)

Comment: Ok, but this is just a 'one time' replace? If so, I still recommend you to use sublime text and do a Ctrl + Shift + F and replace all occurrences.

Comment: @AartikaSethi why not using regex  for searching that word and then replace it.

Comment: What is actually not working? do you get an error message? is the result erroneous?

Comment: @kumar even I thought of regex but couldn't come up with a syntactically correct phrase that can look for spaced words searching..can u recommend any gud link

Comment: @tryph the terms are not getting replaced as in deep learning is still deep learning and not deep_learning

Comment: @AartikaSethi Since you have "deep learning" in your test string and "Deep learning" (with an uppercase d) in your list, it is normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using a `dict` for your replacements:

```
text = "Artificial intelligence is useful for us in every situation of deep learning."
replacements = {"Artificial intelligence" : "Artificial_intelligence",
                "deep learning" : "deep_learning"}
```

Then your approach works (although it is case-sensitive):

```
>>> for rep in replacements:
        text = text.replace(rep, replacements[rep])
>>> print(text)
Artificial_intelligence is useful for us in every situation of deep_learning.
```

For other approaches (like the suggested regex-approach), have a look at [SO: Python replace multiple strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/python-replace-multiple-strings).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a case problem between your list entries and your string, you could use the [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function with [`IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) flag to obtain what you want:

```
import re

list_a = ['Artificial intelligence', 'Deep learning']
list_b = ['artificial_intelligence', 'deep_learning']
text = 'Artificial intelligence is useful for us in every situation of deep learning.'

for from_, to in zip(list_a, list_b):
    text = re.sub(from_, to, text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

print(text)
# artificial_intelligence is useful for us in every situation of deep_learning.
```

Note the use of the [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) function wich allows to iterate over the two lists in the same time.

---

Also note that Christian is right, a dict would be more suitable for your substitution data. The previous code would then be the following for the exact same result:

```
import re

subs = {'Artificial intelligence': 'artificial_intelligence',
        'Deep learning': 'deep_learning'}
text = 'Artificial intelligence is useful for us in every situation of deep learning.'

for from_, to in subs.items():
    text = re.sub(from_, to, text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

print(text)
```