# Pythonic way to remove characters in string

Tags: python, string

What is a neat way to remove different characters from a string? For example, I have the following strings that I need to convert to integers:

```
($12,990)
$21,434
```

I use the following code which works fine, but is there a less bulkier way to do the same?

```
string = string.replace(",", "")
string = string.replace("$", "")
string = string.replace("(", "-")
string = string.replace(")", "")
int(string)
```

Edit: I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: is `string.replace("(", "-")` a typo? That line doesn't remove a character...

Comment: @MSeifert It's Excel formatting for negative numbers to put parenthesis around them

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15448887/223424) is most concise, but the whole thread is excellent, and shows that the problem is not entirely trivial.

Comment: @9000 only if `-` were both a value to be replaced and a value to replace. `str.translate` handles this nicely (and trivially). The question you marked as a duplicate does not seem to use `str.translate` at all.

Comment: @AdamSmith: Yes, for one-character case, `str.translate` is nice. This may suffice in this particular case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), e.g.

```
>>> "($12,990)".translate(str.maketrans({',': '', '$': '', '(': '-', ')': ''}))
'-12990'
```

As stated by @AdamSmith in the comments you could also utilize the (full) three-argument form of [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans):

```
>>> translationtable = str.maketrans("(", "-", ",$)")
>>> "($12,990)".translate(translationtable)
'-12990'
```

---

In case you're using python-2.x the [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) function and [`string.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#string.maketrans) function can be used:

```
>>> import string
>>> translationtable = string.maketrans('(', '-')
>>> "($12,990)".translate(translationtable, ',$)')
'-12990'
```

or with unicodes on Python-2.x you need a unicode-ordinal to unicode-ordinal/string or None:

```
>>> unicode_translation_table = {ord(u','): None, ord(u'$'): None, ord(u'('): ord(u'-'), ord(u')'): None}
>>> u"($12,990)".translate(unicode_translation_table)
u'-12990'
```

Comment: or `str.maketrans("(", "-", ",$)")` [per the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) the three-argument version of `maketrans` pairs the first two arguments and maps the third to `None` (empty string)

Comment: I am getting an error `AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'maketrans'`. I guess that is because I am using Python 2.7. Is there a way to make it work in Python 2.7?

Comment: @sprogissd I included the python 2.7 way of solving it :)

Comment: I get this error `translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)` when I use your solution in Python 2.7 and use a  string variable instead of `"($12,990)"`.

Comment: Seems like the error is caused by unicode. When I do `string.encode('utf-8')`, it works. Is there a way to do it using unicode?

Comment: @sprogissd I updated the answer (again) :)

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't look neat anymore though. I guess I will stick with `.encode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can rely on a loop to make it less ugly:

```
FORBIDDEN_CHARS =  { # Model: { "Replacer" : "Replacees", ... }
 "" : ",$)", 
 "-" : "("
} 

for replacer in FORBIDDEN_CHARS:
 for replacee in FORBIDDEN_CHARS[replacer]:
  mystr = mystr.replace(replacee, replacer)
```

Comment: Yeah sorry for this, then you can rely on an associative dict, let me update

Comment: Updated :-) Sounds correct now

Answer (score -1):

```
''.join(string.strip('(').strip(')').strip('$').split(','))
```

or

```
''.join(filter(str.isdigit, string))
```

Comment: That does not handle parentheses correctly.