# converting a list to integer on python

Tags: python, list, file, int

I was trying to run a code that I wrote
the code reads lines on txt file
so my text file looks like (i've 20 lines)

> ['39', '40', '39', '38', '35', '38', '39', '39', '42', '37', '40', '41', '37', '39', '39', '40', '38', '40', '39', '40']
>
> ['39', '40', '39', '38', '36', '39', '40', '39', '42', '38', '40',
>   '41', '38', '39', '39', '40', '38', '40', '39', '41']
>
> ['39', '40', '40', '38', '36', '39', '40', '39', '43', '38', '40',
>   '41', '38', '39', '39', '40', '38', '40', '39', '41']

i wrote this script to have a new file that looks like this

> 39 40 39 38 35 38 39 39 42 37 40 41 37 39 39 40 38 40 39 40
>
> 39 40 39 38 36 39 40 39 42 38 40 41 38 39 39 40 38 40 39 41
>
> 39 40 40 38 36 39 40 39 43 38 40 41 38 39 39 40 38 40 39 41

the script that i wrote is this one

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

fichier=open("data.txt", "r")
#resultat=open("data_entier.txt", "w")

j=0;

while j < 20:
    lignes= fichier.readline()
    for i in range(len(lignes)):
         lignes[i] = int(lignes[i])

    print(lignes))

    j+=1

fichier.close()
```

the error that I get is this one

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['

Comment: Looks like all you want to do is replace every occurence of ``[``, ``'``, ``,`` and ``]`` with an empty string, correct? For that, you don't need to convert anything to ``int``.

Comment: yea exactlly,
how can i do that ?

Comment: where did `data.txt` come from? It seems you choose to dump lists there initially, rather than the format you actually wanted...

Comment: @DrissAourir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/python-replace-multiple-strings

Comment: data.txt is in the same folder as my .py
its where my lines ar stored.

Comment: But how was `data.txt` generated? By you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string representation of list to list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python)

Comment: @Chris_Rands yea by me 
the data in the file are actually temperature mesures of a 20 sensors that i have

Comment: @DrissAourir Well don't dump your lists to the file like that in the first place then! The suggested solutions are worse than sorting out your issue upstream

Comment: @Chris_Rands Good job breaking down the XY. :) At this point, yes, the best suggestion here would be to first generate the data in to the file properly to not have to face this kind of issue. Ultimately your data should have just been a dump of the numbers without their *list* representations in to the file.

Comment: At this point, what is the best way to proceed with this? It would change the base nature of the question at this point.

Comment: I added an "area of improvement" in my answer to help.

Comment: And the downvote on this question is very unfair. There is an input, expected output, code, exact error and explanation of what is trying to be done. What else are we supposed to expect in terms of a worthy enough question for upvoting?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that when you read in `readline` from your file, you will have a line

```
"['39', '40', '39', '38', '35', '38', '39', '39', '42', '37', '40', '41', '37', '39', '39', '40', '38', '40', '39', '40']\n"
```

As you can see, the first item in your string is `[`. So, you don't actually have the *numbers* structured as you are expecting. Instead, since you seem to already have a *list* structure represented as a string, consider using [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) from `ast`:

```
>>> d = literal_eval(d)
>>> d
['39', '40', '39', '38', '35', '38', '39', '39', '42', '37', '40', '41', '37', '39', '39', '40', '38', '40', '39', '40']
```

Now you actually have a *list* of strings. Now you can proceed modifying *that* to your ints. As a simple process, you can then do something like this:

```
>>> converted_to_ints = map(int, d)
>>> print(list(converted_to_ints))
[39, 40, 39, 38, 35, 38, 39, 39, 42, 37, 40, 41, 37, 39, 39, 40, 38, 40, 39, 40]
```

Note, when it comes to using `map` in Python 3 you get a *map object*, which returns an iterator. So, if you need the *list*, this is why `list` is called when printing. You can read about it here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

## Area of Improvement

Based on the contents of the file you are reading, it would be *best* to not structure the data like this. Instead, what should be done is not setting the data as a list representation in to the file, but just the contents of the list. This avoids having to perform the above solution, and instead, a simple:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
  data = f.read().splitlines() # will remove newline character
  for line in data:
      # perform operations
```

would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You are **not** evaluating the line as a list: every line is just a string that happens to start with a `'['`. So you are iterating over the **characters** of the line.

If the file is like you describe it however, you can easily *evaluate* the line with [**`ast.literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open("data.txt", "r") as fichier:
    for line,_ in zip(fichier,range(20)):
        the_list = literal_eval(line)
        the_list = [int(x) for x in the_list]
        print(the_list))
```

We here used `zip` as a way to obtain the first 20 lines. If you want to process *all* the lines, you can simply use:

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as fichier:
    for line in fichier:
        the_list = literal_eval(line)
        the_list = [int(x) for x in the_list]
        print(the_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reading a line, so you can simply replace the chars you don't want.

```
string = "['39', '40', '39', '38', '35', '38', '39', '39', '42', '37', '40', '41', '37', '39', '39', '40', '38', '40', '39', '40']"
s = string.replace(',','').replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'","")
print s
#output: 39 40 39 38 35 38 39 39 42 37 40 41 37 39 39 40 38 40 39 40
```

Comment: If you are going to go down that route, and knowing what each line looks like, you could have just done `string[1:-2]`. This will remove the first `[` and the trailing `]\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Although in this case the `ast.literal_eval` solutions presented by idjaw and Willem Van Onsem seem as an obvious best fit, let me present another solution:

```
numbers_text = "['39', '40', '39', '38', '35', '38', '39', '39', '42', '37', '40', '41', '37', '39', '39', '40', '38', '40', '39', '40']"
```

Instead of chaining multiple [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) operations, you can use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to get rid of multiple characters in one pass, by providing the third argument to [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans):

> If there is a third argument, it must be a string, whose characters will be mapped to `None` in the result.

Afterwards, we can either use a simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to convert the separate numbers from `str` to `int`:

```
numbers_int = [int(x) for x in numbers_text.translate(str.maketrans("","","[',]")).split()]
```

Or make use of [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
numbers_int = list(map(int, numbers_text.translate(str.maketrans("","","[',]")).split()))
```

Both will result in a new `list` of `int`:

```
[39, 40, 39, 38, 35, 38, 39, 39, 42, 37, 40, 41, 37, 39, 39, 40, 38, 40, 39, 40]
```

Comment: nit: you will most likely have a trailing \n in the string at first.

Comment: @idjaw: yes, but it will be removed by `split()`: `"1 2 3\n".split()` -> `['1', '2', '3']`

Comment: Ah right. Based on your solution that is correct. I had `split(',')` in my head, which would not have done that.