# Replacing multiple string values in one go

Tags: python

Hey guys how can I replace multiple numbers in a string for their values specified in a dict in one go? ex:

```
dic_lanches = {10:'Misto-Quente',11:'X-Burger',
               12:'X-Salada',
               13:'X-Egg',
               14:'X-Bacon',
               15:'X-Calabresa',
               16:'X-Frango',
               17:'X-Coração',
               18:'X-Casa'}

my_string = 11 12 13
```

after replace:

I want `X-Burguer X-Salada X-Egg`

But what I am getting is:

```
X-Burguer 12 13

11 X-Salada 13

11 12 X-Egg
```

now tried:

```
result = re.sub(r'\d', lambda x: dic_lanches[int(x.group())], myString)
```

but I'm getting KeyError 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python replace multiple strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/python-replace-multiple-strings)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
myString = "I want 11 12 13"
result = re.sub(r'\d', lambda x: dic_lanches[int(x.group())], myString)
```

What we are doing here is we use regex to match all numbers in the string, then we replace those numbers with the string in the dict that has the corresponding key.

Comment: Tried what U said, but I'm now getting KeyError 1