# What is the efficient way to replace string on python?

Tags: python-3.x, text, text-mining

I have large amounts of list for replacement like below.

The remplacement file `list.txt`:

```
人の,NN
人の名前,FF
```

And the data in which to replace `text.txt` :

```
aaa人の abc 人の名前def ghi
```

I want to replace this text to like below using `list.txt`.

```
>>> my_func('aaa人の abc 人の名前def ghi')
'aaaNN abc FFdef ghi'
```

This is my code. But I think this is quite inefficiency to process large data.

```
d = {}
with open('list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        d[line.split(',')[0]] = line.split(',')[1]

with open('text.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    txt = f.read()

st = 0
lst = []

# \u4e00-\u9fea\u3040-\u309f] means the range of unicode of Japanese character
for match in re.finditer(r"([\u4e00-\u9fea\u3040-\u309f]+)", txt):
    st_m, ed_m = match.span()
    lst.append(txt[st:st_m])

    search = txt[st_m:ed_m]
    rpld = d[search]
    lst.append(rpld)

    st = ed_m

lst.append(txt[st:])

print(''.join(lst))
```

Please let me know better way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string

Comment: @Arnaud No it can't be the solution. rep = {'a':'1', 'aa':'2'}   pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))], "a and aa") => The output string is '1 and 11'. But in my case it should be '1 and 2'.

Comment: What if you just order your replacements by alphabetical order but decreasing length s.t. longer patterns be replace before -- and thus avoid conflicts ? Also, this thread I point to has **a lot** of answers with high votes, within some that discuss your issue.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your input `aaa人の abc 人の名前def ghi` I see you have `white-spaces` in between. So it's not really a `word replace` it's more of a `phrase replace`.

> You can refer to the edit history to see the old answer in case you want `word replacement`

In such a case that you have phrase replacement, you can use `re` (reg-ex) and provide a array of replacements. Below is an implementation:

```
>>> import re
>>> _regex = {r'aaa人の abc 人の名前def ghi': r'人の,NN 人の名前,FF'}
>>> input_string = 'hi aaa人の abc 人の名前def ghi work'
>>> for pattern in _regex.keys():
        input_string = re.sub(pattern, _regex[pattern], input_string)


>>> input_string
'hi 人の,NN 人の名前,FF work'
>>>
```

Below is an `object oriented` implementation of the above

```
import csv
import re


class RegexCleanser(object):
    _regex = None

    def __init__(self, input_string: str):
        self._input_string = input_string
        self._regex = self._fetch_rows_as_dict_keys(r'C:\Users\adity\Desktop\japsyn.csv')

    @staticmethod
    def _fetch_rows_as_dict_keys(file_path: str) -> dict:
        """
        Reads the data from the file
        :param file_path: the path of the file that holds the lookup data
        :return: the read data
        """
        try:
            word_map = {}
            for line in csv.reader(open(file_path, encoding='UTF-8')):
                word, syn = line
                word_map[word] = syn
            return word_map
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f'Could not find the file at {file_path}')

    def clean(self)-> str:
        for pattern in self._regex.keys():
            self._input_string = re.sub(pattern, self._regex[pattern], self._input_string)
        return self._input_string
```

**Usage:**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cleaner = RegexCleanser(r'hi aaa人の abc 人の名前def ghi I dont know this language.')
    clean_string = cleaner.clean()
    print(clean_string)
```

Comment: When I use 'aaa人の abc 人の名前def ghi' as input_string and

人の,NN
人の名前,FF

as 'synonyms.csv', it's not replaced.

Comment: @Bryan What language is this?

Comment: Some of Japanese characters are included in my sample.

Comment: @Bryan Great so what you can do is, put them in a `csv` too. Now use `string encoding` to actually define it. Since `strings` are just sequence of `bytes`. You can use `UTF-8` or even `UTF-32` or you can also use `Unicode` as the encoding format for the `csv`. Can you please share an input string and what it needs to be replaced with. I can wrap a demo around it

Comment: Thank you for your help. But your code is not what I want. Please read my edited post again.