# Replacing multiple strings in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.7, replace

I currently have the below Python code which works well:-

```
caseURL = r"\\mydomain\abc\lp_t\GB\123456\Original Format"
caseURL = caseURL.replace("lp_t", "lp_i")
caseURL = caseURL.replace("Original Format", "1")
```

This works fine as said and carries out the below conversion:-

```
\\mydomain\abc\lp_t\GB\123456\Original Format 
\\mydomain\abc\lp_i\GB\123456\1\
```

This however just seems a bit clumsy. Is there a more pythonesque way to perform these two segment replacements?

Thanks

Comment: The other way I can think of is regex. Would you like a solution in that

Comment: The only thing you might want to consider is to chain several replacements: `caseURL = caseURL.replace("lp_t", "lp_i").replace("Original Format", "1")`

Answer (score 0):

**A similar post already exists**:
[How to replace multiple substrings of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string)

You can pick one answer from multiple options in the above post.