# Find from a list of strings, from a list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, for-loop

I need help looping through a list of sentences/strings, and erase the string characters forwards, based on another list with words.

```
sentences = ['im not george smith my name is lucas mangulu thank you',
             'how shall i call you george smith oh okay got it'
             'we have detected a miyagi chung in the traffic flow']

words = ['lucas mangulu', 'george smith', 'miyagi chung']
```

I know I have to loop for each element in the *sentences* list. But then I'm stuck on how to find() for example in the same element in the *words* list into the *sentences* list. So that the final results should be:

```
sentences = ['im not george smith my name is',
             'how shall i call you'
             'we have detected a']

#OR

sentences = ['im not george smith my name is lucas mangulu',
             'how shall i call you george smith'
             'we have detected a miyagi chung']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace multiple substrings of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string)

Comment: To answer the question on how to find the sentence, in python `'my name is lucas mangulu thank you'.find('lucas mangulu')` will return 11, which is the position of `'lucas mangulu`' in the string. From there you can use substring operation to extract what you need.

Comment: Your example output is messed up and confusing. In your first output: `['im not george smith my name is',` you left `george smith` but in the others you remove all names. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I have dificulties understanding what you are looking for exactly, but here is a simple idea to remove the string in `words` from the strings in `sentences`; this is using a many calls to `str.replace()`.

```
>>> words = ['lucas mangulu', 'george smith', 'miyagi chung']
>>> original_sentences = [
...     'im not george smith my name is lucas mangulu thank you',
...     'how shall i call you george smith oh okay got it',
...     'we have detected a miyagi chung in the traffic flow',
... ]
>>> original_sentences
['im not george smith my name is lucas mangulu thank you',
 'how shall i call you george smith oh okay got it',
 'we have detected a miyagi chung in the traffic flow']

>>> sentences = list(original_sentences)                  # make a copy
>>> for i in range(len(sentences)):
...     for w in words:                                   # remove words
...         sentences[i] = sentences[i].replace(w, '')
...     while '  ' in sentences[i]:                       # remove double whitespaces
...         sentences[i] = sentences[i].replace('  ', ' ')
>>> sentences
['im not my name is thank you',
 'how shall i call you oh okay got it',
 'we have detected a in the traffic flow']
```

Is this what you intended to do?

---

If you only want to replace one word in all the sentences, you could remove the nested for loop:

```
>>> sentences = list(original_sentences)                  # make a copy
>>> word_to_remove = words[0]                             # pick one
>>> for i in range(len(sentences)):
...     sentences[i] = sentences[i].replace(word_to_remove, '')
>>> sentences
['im not george smith my name is  thank you',
 'how shall i call you george smith oh okay got it',
 'we have detected a miyagi chung in the traffic flow']
```

Comment: Hi Ralf, that looks nice, the only thing is that I got to replace for each element. element  [0] of words and sentences. so my result for element [0] of sentences should be: 'im not george smith my name is'

Comment: @LucasMengual I don't think I understand completely, but I edited my answer to add another idea.

Answer (score 0):

You give two example outputs for one input, which is extremely confusing.
The following code may help you but I can't logically figure out how to match your example exactly.

That being said I have a hunch this is what you are looking for.

```
import re
sentences = ['im not george smith my name is lucas mangulu thank you',
             'how shall i call you george smith oh okay got it',
             'we have detected a miyagi chung in the traffic flow',
             'Is this valid?']

words = ['lucas mangulu', 'george smith', 'miyagi chung', 'test']
ocurrences = []
for sentence in sentences:
    # If you want to find all occurences in a sentence this line will help you
    # ocurrences.append([(x.start(), x.end(), x.group()) for x in re.finditer('|'.join(words), sentence)])

    # Look for a word in this sentence (the first occurrence of that word)
    search_result = re.search('|'.join(words), sentence)
    # If we found a word in this sentence
    if search_result:
        ocurrences.append((search_result.start(), search_result.end(), search_result.group()))
    else: # No word found
        ocurrences.append((0, 0, None))

# Example output 1:
# oc in this case is (start_index, end_index, word_found) for each sentence.
for index, oc in enumerate(ocurrences):
  print(sentences[index][:oc[1]])

# Example output 2"
for index, oc in enumerate(ocurrences):
  print(sentences[index][:oc[0]])
```

**Example output 1:**

> im not george smith
>   how shall i call you george smith
>   we have detected a miyagi chung

**Example output 2:**

> im not
>   how shall i call you
>   we have detected a