# Renaming multiple pandas columns with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to tidy up a csv I was given where the columns are not very developer-friendly right now. I would like to use regular expressions to find multiple patterns in the column names to replace multiple conditions. For example, given df1 with `leading/trailed spaces`, `white space` throughout the header, parenthesis `()`, and `<`, then I would like remove the `leading/trailing spaces` and `parenthesis`, replace the `white space` with `_`, and replace the `<` with `LESS_THAN`

For example, turning df1 into df2:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({' APPLES AND LEMONS': [1,2], ' ORANGES ([POUNDS]) ': [2,1], ' BANANAS < 5 ': [8,9]})

APPLES AND LEMONS   ORANGES (POUNDS)    BANANAS < 5

0                   1                     2              8
1                   2                     1              9

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'APPLES_AND_LEMONS': [1,2], 'ORANGES_POUNDS': [2,1], 'BANANAS_LESS_THAN_5 ': [8,9]})

   APPLES_AND_LEMONS  ORANGES_POUNDS  BANANAS_LESS_THAN_5
0                  1               2                     8
1                  2               1                     9
```

My current implementation is by just chaining a bunch of str.replaces. Is there a better way to do this? I was thinking that regular expressions could be especially useful because there are hundreds of columns and I'm sure that there will be a few more headaches that I have yet to find.

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.strip()
df1.columns = concatenated_df.columns.str.replace(' ','_').str.replace('<','LESS_THAN').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')','')
```

Comment: The `columns` object is typically small, so just specify a dict (or OrderedDict if order matters) of `{pat: repl}` and iterate over the `.items()`. For instance see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string. It's basically the same, though slightly more readable.

Comment: no, your approach is entirely reasonable

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the link Alollz gave me I was able to get a solution that is much easier to maintain than continuously chaining `str.replace`

```
def clean_column_names(df):

    df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
    replace_dict = {' ': '_', '<': 'LESS_THAN', '(': '', ')':''}
    for i, j in replace_dict.items():
        new_columns = [column.replace(i, j) for column in df.columns]
        df.columns = new_columns

    return df

clean_column_names(df1)

   APPLES_AND_LEMONS  ORANGES_POUNDS  BANANAS_LESS_THAN_5
0                  1                 2                    8
1                  2                 1                    9
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is better for you.

```
old_cols = list(df1.columns.values)

remove = re.compile(r'^\s+|\s+$|[\(\)\[\]]')
wspace = re.compile(r'\s+')
less = re.compile(r'<')
great = re.compile(r'>')

new_cols = []

for i in old_cols:
    i = re.sub(remove, "", i)
    i = re.sub(wspace, "_", i)
    i = re.sub(less, "LESS_THAN", i)
    i = re.sub(less, "GREATER_THAN", i)
    new_cols.append(i)

df1.columns = new_cols
```