# How to replace a certain word in a dataframe only if it's preceded by a number?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to search in a dataframe about certain words listed in dictionary values if any exist it will replaced with the key of values.

```
units_dic= {'grams':['g','Grams'],
                'kg'   :['kilogram','kilograms']}
```

the problem is some units abbreviations are letters so it will replace all letters also, I want to do the replacement only if it preceded by a number to make sure it's a unit.

**Dataframe**

```
    Id | test 
    ---------
    1  |'A small paperclip has a mass of about 111 g'
    2  |'1 kilogram =1000 g'
    3  |'g is the 7th letter in the ISO basic Latin alphabet'
```

**Replacement Loop**

```
  x = df.copy()
  for k in units_dic:
      for i in range(len(x['test'])):
          for w in units_dic[k]:
              x['test'][i] = str(x['test'][i]).replace(str(w), str(k))
```

**The Output**

```
    Id | test 
    ---------
    1  |'A small paperclip has a mass of about 111 grams'
    2  |'1 kg =1000 grams'
    3  |'grams is the 7th letter in the ISO basic Latin alphabet'
```

Comment: FYI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions to the rescue along with flipping the dictionary.

```
import re

d = {i: k for k, v in units_dic.items() for i in v}
u = r'|'.join(d)
v = fr'(\d+\s?)\b({u})\b'

df.assign(test=[re.sub(v, lambda x: x.group(1) + d[x.group(2)], el) for el in df.test])
```

```
   Id                                               test
0   1    A small paperclip has a mass of about 111 grams
1   2                                   1 kg =1000 grams
2   3  g is the 7th letter in the ISO basic Latin alp...
```

Comment: Nothing has changed

Comment: `df.assign` isn't in-place, you need to store the result

Comment: @R_Developer `df = df.assign...`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for key, val in units_dic.items(): 
    df['test'] = df['test'].replace("\d+[ ]*" + "|".join(val) , key , regex=True)
```

Comment: If there is no space between the number and abbreviations it will remove the number

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of the `lookbehind` feature of `regex` here, which we can specify that it needs to be preceded by a number and *optional* a whitespace:

```
for k, v in units_dic.items():
    df['test'] = df['test'].str.replace(f"(?<=[0-9])\s*({'|'.join(v)})\b", f' {k}')
```

---

```
print(df)
   Id                                               test
0   1  'A small paperclip has a mass of about 111 grams'
1   2                                 '1 kg =1000 grams'
2   3  'g is the 7th letter in the ISO basic Latin al...
```

**Explanation**
First we use raw + fstring: `fr'sometext'`

Regular expression:

- `?<=[0-9]` = preceded by a number
- `\s*` is a whitespace
- `"|".join(v)`
  gives us the values in your dictionary back delimited by a `|` which
  is the `or` operator in regex

Comment: Be careful here, the string `45 grapes` would become `45 gramsrapes`.  Also, for large dictionaries, you are making potentially a *lot* of replacements when you can do it all in one pass, all of which are fairly slow using `str.replace`.  Finally, if no space is found between the number and the abbreviation, this will add a space

Comment: what if I want the the opposite (abbreviation then digit ) I tried this (str.replace(f"{v}\s(?<=[0-9])\b", f' {k}'))