# Replace item in list with one of several options given its contents

Tags: python, string, replace

As in:
`data = data.replace(['a', 'b', 'c'], [0, 1, 2])`

Given 'a' replace with 0. Given 'b' replace with 1. Given 'c' replace with 2.

I see there is ways to do it with regex, but I want to know if I can do it something like the above.

Currently it's failing, because it thinks I'm trying to replace a list with a list.

Comment: Lists don't have a `.replace()` method.  What type is `data`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to create pairs which you want replace and iterate other dictonary:

```
replace_pairs = { 'a': '0', 'b': '1', 'c': '2' }

data = 'abcba'

for key, value in replace_pairs.items():
    data = data.replace(key, value)
```

Output:

```
>> data = '01210'
```

I would recommend the regex method, because the runtime is much shorter: [How to replace multiple substrings of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string)