# python3 split method doesn't register my regex expression

Tags: python-3.x, regex

### Current Problem

I've pieced together a script which downloads attachments from a mailbox in gmail and for the most part pulls a list of variables based on the email the information is pulled from. However I found that in some cases the "Message ID" of an email could be listed as "Message ID" or "Message-ID". Because of this I've tried to use regex to take into account that there could be anything between "Message" and "ID" but my code spits out errors regardless of what I have tried to so far with the expression.

### Error

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "email-downloader.py", line
> 64, in <module>
>     msg_id = str(email_message).split("Message+\.*: ", 1)[1].split("\n", 1)[0] IndexError: list index out of range
```

### What I've tried

I've looked online and wasn't able to find an answer in the past which was able to resolve this issue. I also tried to amend the regex with different `+` placements or the use of `\` and `[]`

### Code

```
        email_from = str(email_message).split("From: ", 1)[1].split("\n", 1)[0]
        subject = str(email_message).split("Subject: ", 1)[1].split("\n", 1)[0]
        ext = os.path.splitext(fileName)[1]
        delivered = str(email_message).split("Date: ", 1)[1].split("\n", 1)[0]
        msg_id = str(email_message).split("Message+\.*: ", 1)[1].split("\n", 1)[0]

        print('File: "{file}".'.format(file=fileName))
        print('Ext: "{ext}".'.format(ext=ext))
        print('Subject: "{subject}".'.format(subject=subject))
        print('From: "{email_from}".'.format(email_from=email_from))
        print('Date Delivered: "{delivered}".'.format(delivered=delivered))
        print('Message ID: "{msg_id}".'.format(msg_id=msg_id))
        print("\n")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        print('"{msg_id}"   "{delivered}"   "{file}"        "{subject}"     "{email_from}"'.format(file=fileName,subject=subject,email_from=email_from,msg_id=msg_id,delivered=delivered), file=open("array/client-ref.tsv", "a"))
        os.rename(os.path.join(dirName,fileName), os.path.join(dirName,msg_id + ext))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `split()` method does not work with regex. You would need to import the regex library `re` and use `re.split()` in order to achieve what you want. If "Message ID" and "Message-ID" are the only two possibilities, you don't have to use regex though. You could first replace one expression with the other, and then split the text:

```
msg_id = str(email_message).replace('Message-ID', 'Message ID', 1)
msg_id = msg_id.split("Message ID", 1)[1].split("\n", 1)[0]
```

As a side note, I don't know what `type` `email_message` is, but it makes sense to convert it to a `str` only once and store it in another variable e.g., if you need `email_message` in its original `type` later on. I wouldn't recomment to convert it to a `str` more than once.

Comment: worked a treat. I'm still only sampling some emails of a larger batch at the moment so there could be other variations down the line. Do you know if `replace` supports the option for multiple values or if there is a different method one would need to use? First time trying to write python so I'm still trying to get my head around what I can and can't get away with.

Comment: `replace` also only takes one argument. But if you would like to be more flexible, I recommend you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59072515/5472354). It also mentions [flashtext](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/11/flashtext-a-library-faster-than-regular-expressions/), wich is appearently even faster than regex, but I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

To use regular expressions for splitting a string, you have to use the `split(pattern, string)` method from the `re` library in python. The following code should do what you want

```
import re
msg_id = re.split("Message.*: ", str(email_message))[1].split("\n", 1)[0]
```