# Random nucleotides sequence

Tags: python

i started learning python today and i had this project in mind where the code would generate a random nucleotides sequence. This is the code im using for now its its working perfectly fine

```
import random
import string
nuc = '*Chaine aleatoire de nucleotides (Brin transcrit)*     :'
nucBNT = '*Chaine aleatoire de nucleotides (Brin non transcrit)* :'
nucleotides_length = 30
possible_characters = "ATCG"
random_character_list = [random.choice(possible_characters) for i in range(nucleotides_length)]
random_nucleotides = "".join(random_character_list)
print(nuc, random_nucleotides)
```

I was then thinking about it generating the completing nucleotide sequence ( replacing Adenine by Thymine, Guanine by Cytosine, Thymine by Adenine and Cytosine by Guanine) but this is my first time opening Python and i dont know any way on how to do this despite looking on internet. Any help would be highly appreciated

Have a great day

Comment: You should work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest* way would be to set up a dictionary with an entry for each substitution. The keys (on the left) are the inputs, and the values (on the right) are what you want to replace each one with:

```py
substitute = {
    "A": "T",
    "G": "C",
    "T": "A",
    "C": "G",
}
```

Then you can use this to replace each character in `random_nucleotides`, character-by-character:

```py
completed_nucleotides = "".join([substitute[c] for c in random_nucleotides])
```

<sub>* for a certain value of "simplest", anyway</sub>

---

There are a number of general solutions out there for making multiple substitutions to a string using `string.replace` or `re.sub`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59072515/2449857) maybe is the most complete list of them. However in this case the substitutions are cyclic(?): the `A`s and `T`s swap, and the `C`s and `G`s swap. If you replace characters across the whole string at once, you replace all the `A`s with `T`s, then all the `T`s with `A`s, and you're left with only `A`s and no `T`s.

You could remove the cyclic condition by having one string be lowercase. Then you could use one of the more common multiple-substitutions-in-a-string method.

Comment: Appreciated it a lot, but i still have a last question, what if i want to add an other sequence where T will be replaced by U for the ARN ? And again thanks you very much

Comment: No problem! You'd just make a different `substitute` dictionary which has `"T": "U"`.

Comment: substitute = {
    "T": "U",
}

arn_messager = "".join([substitute[c] for c in completed_nucleotides])
print(arnM, arn_messager)

like this ?

Comment: That'd work, but if you're only making one kind of substitution you can use `arn_messager = completed_nucleotides.replace("T", "U")`. If you were making `arn_messager` from `random_nucleotides` you could make a second dictionary with 4 entries including `"T": "U"` - but you'd better give them both better names than `substitute`!