# Is there a shorter way to replace words in a string?

Tags: python, str-replace

**This is my task**

```
journey = """Just a small tone girl
Leaving in a lonely whirl
She took the midnight tray going anywhere
Just a seedy boy
Bored and raised in South Detroit or something
He took the midnight tray going anywhere"""
```

Gross. Okay, so for this exercise, your job is to use Python's string replace method to fix this string up and print the new version out to the console.

**This is what I did**

```
journey = """ just a small tone girl
Leaving in a lonely whirl
she took a midnight tray going anywhere
Just a seedy boy
bored and raised in south detroit or something
He took the midnight tray going anywhere"""

journeyEdit = journey.replace("tone" , 
"town").replace("tray","train").replace("seedy","city").replace("Leaving", 
"living").replace("bored","born").replace("whirl","world").replace("or 
something", " ")

print (journeyEdit)
```

Comment: Was there a shorter way?

Comment: Well, this is somehow shorter but the fact is, it's not efficient. You can rather ask for an efficient way which might I think you are up to.

Comment: Use a dict? `y  = d.get(x, x)`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a sample way to replace words from text. you can use **python re**  package.

please find the below code for your guidance.

```
import re
journey = """ just a small tone girl Leaving in a lonely whirl she took a 
midnight tray going anywhere Just a seedy boy bored and raised in south 
detroit or something He took the midnight tray going anywhere"""
# define desired replacements here

journeydict = {"tone" : "town",
          "tray":"train",
          "seedy":"city",
          "Leaving": "living",
          "bored":"born",
          "whirl":"world"
          }

# use these given three lines to do the replacement
rep = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in journeydict.items()) 
#Python 3 renamed dict.iteritems to dict.items so use rep.items() for latest 
versions
pattern = re.compile("|".join(journeydict.keys()))
text = pattern.sub(lambda m: journeydict[re.escape(m.group(0))], journey)

print(journey)
print(text)
```

Comment: How can i use this but in a INSENSITIVE case? I tried to add the flags re.I, but I fail in the attempt

Answer (score 2):

Probably a longer way than you given ;-).

As given at [How to replace multiple substrings of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string):

```
import re

journey = """ just a small tone girl Leaving in a lonely whirl she took a 
midnight tray going anywhere Just a seedy boy bored and raised in south 
detroit or something He took the midnight tray going anywhere"""

rep = {"tone": "town",
       "tray": "train",
       "seedy":"city",
       "Leaving": "living",
       "bored":"born",
       "whirl":"world",
       "or something": " "}

# use these three lines to do the replacement
rep = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in rep.iteritems())

# Python 3 renamed dict.iteritems to dict.items so use rep.items() for latest versions
pattern = re.compile("|".join(rep.keys()))

journeyEdit = pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))], journey)

print(journeyEdit)
```