# Parsing the DOM to extract data using Python

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code that outputs data extracted from `<div>` tag.

```py
s = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

best_price_tags = s.findAll('div', "flt-subhead1 gws-flights-results__price gws-flights-results__cheapest-price")
best_prices = []
for tag in best_price_tags:
    best_prices.append(tag.text.replace('€', '').strip())
```

The first element of the variable `best_price_tags` contains the following:

```
<div class="flt-subhead1 gws-flights-results__price gws-flights-results__cheapest-price">      1 820 €   </div>
```

I am expecting from the above code to output only the value 1821.

The above code chunk has a problem where it outputs the following, consider the case of `best_price_tags[0]`, `'1\u202f821'`.

I tried the following but unfortunately did not work for me.

```
for tag in best_price_tags:
    best_prices.append(int(tag.text.replace('€', '').strip()))
```

Looking for an automated solution without using NLP modules.

NOTE: I have edited the exact value `<div>` tag has. It was `<div class='...'>1 820 €</div>` and now it is `<div class='...'>      1 820 €   </div>`.

Comment: `print(repr(tag.text))` and then work on creating a [mcve].

Comment: \u202f is unicode for the small space between the 1 and the 8, are you using python 3?

Comment: Thanks @RoyZwambag, I am using Python 3 in Jupyter notebook.

Comment: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202f/index.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the space in 1 821 seems to be a no-break space (causing the \u202f in the output), try doing a replace on this too. By the way, I don't know where this character is on a keyboard, but copy/paste should be enough

Comment: Thanks, @malmiteria. Your idea works but I have to write all this line after the `for` loop, `best_prices.append(tag.text.replace('\xa0€', '').replace('\u202f', '').strip())` the think which I consider not a pythonic way, isn't it?

Comment: Well I don't know for sure, but I don't know how to do it otherwise, there is a discussion about it there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string

Comment: check my updated post concerning the exactly value `<div>` tag has.

Comment: Still needs to be checked if we can remove all spaces in the value that `<div>` tag has, which then it remains only to write `int(tag.text.replace('€', ''))`.

Comment: doesn't `.strip()` remove all the extra whitespace?

Comment: Yes, it does but not what in between the number. It removes spaces which are in the right and left of 1 820 €.