# How to use Regex to replace string?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string and I want to change it using regex:

```
import re 
s1 = "FirstName0001LastName0001"
s2 = re.sub('LastName', 'FamilyName', s1)
s2 = re.sub('FirstName', 'Contact', s1)
```

Expected Result **s2 = "Contact0001FamilyName0001"**,
Is there any other way to do this in one line of code?

Comment: What's the point of the `s2 = re.sub('LastName', 'FamilyName', s1)` line? It doesn't seem relevant here (unless your expected result is wrong). Also, you probably don't need regex for this. `s2 = s1.replace("FirstName", "Contact")` is sufficient.

Comment: You do not use the first substitution result when you run `s2 = re.sub('FirstName', 'Contact', s1)`, why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may get downvoted for doing this, but:

```py
s1 = "FirstName0001LastName0001"
s2 = s1.replace('LastName', 'FamilyName').replace('FirstName', 'Contact')
print(s2)  # prints Contact0001FamilyName0001
```

You may not even need to use a `re.sub` regex replacement here, and you can just chain the replacement calls in a single line.