# if statement in python to prevent replacing happening twice for a letter?

Tags: python, string, replace

So I currently have a string, and one by one I'm replacing each letter.

```
string = "beoffokefkoeffewlewfkoz"
string = string.replace("F","E") #E
string = string.replace("R","H") #H
string = string.replace("C","T") #T
string = string.replace("W","Z") #Z
print(string)
```

However,I've noticed that if I use any letter which I've used previously, it'll replace the letter I actually want it to be.. so if I change C to T, then I look for any T's in my string and replace them with say W, it now changes T  to W. How do I prevent this from happening? I just want that one specific letter change to a specific letter happen once.

Comment: This code doesn't change `string` at all.

Comment: use str.translate() and str.maketrans() to make all the replacmenets at once

Comment: python is case sensitive.  You are finding and replacing capital letter and your string has small letters. Please provide expected output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace multiple substrings of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string)

Comment: @Chris_Rands this worked, thank you.