# How to replace a list of strings of a string?

Tags: python, string, replace

How can I get the string "Hello World" using a list of strings in the code below?
I'm trying:

```
str1="HellXXo WoYYrld"
replacers = ["YY", "XX"]

str1.replace(replacers, "")
```

Which results in this error:

```
TypeError: replace() argument 1 must be str, not list
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should pass one element from replacers to `replace` (which is `str`), not the whole list which is `list`

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An efficient method that won't require to read **again** the string for each replacer is to use a regex:

```
str1="HellXXo WoYYrld"
replacers = ["YY", "XX"]

import re
re.sub('|'.join(replacers), '', str1)
```

output: `Hello World`

Answer (score 3):

`replace` takes only a string as its first argument and not a list of strings.

You can either loop over the individual substrings you want to replace:

```
str1="HellXXo WoYYrld"
replacers = ["YY", "XX"]
for s in replacers:
  str1 = str1.replace(s, "")
print(str1)
```

or you can use regexes to do this:

```
import re
str1="HellXXo WoYYrld"
replacers = ["YY", "XX"]
re.sub('|'.join(replacers), '', str1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to repeatedly use `.replace` for example using `for` loop

```
str1="HellXXo WoYYrld"
replacers = ["YY", "XX"]
for rep in replacers:
    str1 = str1.replace(rep, "")
print(str1)
```

output

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 1):

you should iterate through your list of replacers Try This solution:

```
str1="HellXXo WoYYrld"
replacers = ["YY", "XX"]
for elem in replacers:
  str1=str1.replace(elem, "")
  
print(str1)
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a regex but it depends of your use case for example:

```
 regex = r"("+ ")|(".join(replacers)+ ")"
```

in your case creates this regular expression: `(XX)|(YYY)`
then you could use re.sub:

```
re.sub(regex, "", a)
```

the alternative could be just use a for loop and replace the values in replacers