# Using regex sub on a df.column with apply in pandas df

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a df as such:

```
data= [{'Employees at store': 18, 'store': 'Mikes&Carls P@rlor', 'hair cut inch':'$3'},
        {'Employees at store': 5, 'store': 'Over-Top', 'hair cut inch': '$9'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

& have

```
df=df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower().str.replace(' ','_')
                      if isinstance(x, object)
                      else x)
```

working for repalacing spaces with underscores. I know that you can link these per [How to replace multiple substrings of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string) .

And I also know that the link the exact string, not a subpart of it having tried:

```
df=df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower().str.
            replace(' ','_').str.
            replace('&','and').str.
            replace('@','a') if isinstance(x, object) else x)
```

I think I have to use re.sub and do something like this `re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9_ \n\.]', '', my_str)`
and can't figure out how to build it into my apply(lambda...) function.

Comment: What is expected ouput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a callable to [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html). Use a dictionary with the list of replacements and use the `get` method:

```
maps = {' ': '_', '&': 'and', '@': 'a'}
df['store'].str.replace('[ &@]', lambda m: maps.get(m.group(), ''), regex=True)
```

output:

```
0    MikesandCarls_Parlor
1                Over-Top
Name: store, dtype: object
```

##### applying on all (string) columns

```
cols = df.select_dtypes('object').columns

maps = {' ': '_', '&': 'and', '@': 'a', '$': '€'}
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda col: col.str.replace('[ &@$]', lambda m: maps.get(m.group(), ''), regex=True))
```

output:

```
   Employees at store                 store hair cut inch
0                  18  MikesandCarls_Parlor            €3
1                   5              Over-Top            €9
```

##### replacement per column

```
cols = df.select_dtypes('object').columns

maps = {'store': {' ': '_', '&': 'and', '@': 'a', '$': '€'},
        'hair cut inch': {'$': '€'}
       }

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda col: col.str.replace('[ &@$]', 
                          lambda m: maps.get(col, {}).get(m.group(), ''),
                          regex=True))
```

Comment: wrap `'` in double quotes: `{"'": ''}`, or escape `{'\'': ''}`