# Replace character in file more than two times

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function "decode" which takes `key`, `filename`, and `indicator` parameters. `key` is to indicates the character that needs to replace in the file. `filename` indicates the name of the file, and `indicator` indicates whether to encode or decode. Now with the code, I wrote below, no value was passing into `filecontent` when it loops the second time. What might be the issue here?

```
   def decode(key, filename, indicator):
        key = list(key)
        openfile = open(filename,'rt')
        if indicator == 'd':
            if len(key) % 2 > 0:
                return
            else:
                for i in range(0, len(key), 2):
                    key[i] = key[i].lower()
                    key[i+1] = key[i+1].lower()
                    indiOne = key[i+1]
                    indiTwo = key[i]
                    filecontent = openfile.read().replace(indiOne, indiTwo)
                print(filecontent)
        return ''

if __name__ == '__main__':
   print(decode('VFSC', 'decript.txt', 'd'))
```

here is the content in decript.txt:

```
I lofe eating cpanish apples.
```

and it was meant to replace all the F with V and C with S:

```
I love eating spanish apples.
```

Comment: Why are you using `read` in a loop? Do you know what it does?

Comment: Instead of calling `.lower()` on each element every time, wouldn't it be easier to just do `key = list(key.lower())`?

Comment: This is an unusual way to test for odd length: `if len(key) % 2 > 0`. You would typically write: `if len(key) % 2 != 0` or simply `if len(key) % 2`.

Comment: Here is how to do the replacement better: [How to replace multiple substrings of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6116978/6045800)

Answer (score 2):

Place this above the loop: `filecontent = openfile.read()`

Then modify the line inside the loop to look like this:

`filecontent = filecontent.replace(indiOne, indiTwo)`

This reads from the file only once, and then modifies the same object.  The way it is shown, it's being overwritten every loop.