# My string letter replacement code doesn't work

Tags: python, string, replace

```
import re
text = input("Enter text: ")
text = text.lower()
len = len(text)
lenid = len - 1

def translate(text):
    translation = ""
    slocid = text.index("s")
    for letter in text:
        if (text[lenid] == "s") or (text[slocid + 1] == " "):
          translation = re.sub(r"s\b", lambda m: m.group().replace("s", "ς"), text)
        if letter == "s":
          translation = translation.replace("s", "σ")
        if letter == "a":
            translation = translation + "α"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
    return translation

print(translate(text))
```

I want to make a program where, when I enter a text, I get back the same text but

- all the `"s"` at the end of a word are replaced with `"ς"`
- if they're not at the end of the word, I want the `"s"` to be replaced with `"σ"`.
- If the letter is `"a"` I want it replaced with `"α"`.

I'm trying to make a Greeklish to Greek translator and it just seems I messed up.

---

input: `"as"`

output: `"aςs"`

what I want: `"ας"`

---

input: `"sa"`

output: `"sa"`

what I want: `"σα"`

---

input: `"sakas"`

output: `"σakaςs"`

what I want: `"σαkας"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently translate the text character by character, but your regex and `replace` work on the whole string so you can just apply them to the whole string instead.

```
def translate(text):
    return re.sub(r"s\b", "ς", text)\
           .replace("s", "σ")\
           .replace("a", "α")
```

This will first sub your regex to replace ending 's' characters, then replaces the remaining 's' characters and then the 'a' characters.

Comment: Thank you, also what is the exact purpose of r"s\b"?

Comment: Hi, for reference, this deals with the same problem and is the function I am using: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15448887/1793606

Comment: `s\b` is a regular expression. It means a literal s character followed by a word boundary. This basically just means it will only match s characters at the end of a word. The r in front of the string makes it a raw string so you don't have to use double backslashes.

Comment: You can see an interactive example of the regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/qGOIK4/1).

Answer (score -1):

If you wanna understand the logic behind, the following code will help you understand how does it works.

```
def translate(text):
# checks 's' is present in 'text'
if 's' in text:
    # checks if 's' appears at the end of 'text'
    if text[-1] == 's':
        # checks if 's' appears between 'tex'
        if 's' in text[:-1]:
            text = text.replace('s', 'σ')

        # replace 's' with 'ς'
        text = text[:-1] + 'ς'
    else:
        # replace 's' with 'σ'
        text = text.replace('s', 'σ')

# checks 'a' is present in 'text'
if 'a' in text:
    # replace 'a' with 'α'
    text = text.replace('a', 'α')

return text
```