# How to remove single quotes and double quotes in csv file without pandas

Tags: python, csv, csvreader

I am printing the each data in csv file.While reading it was showing SingleQuotes and double quotes.I need to remove if it has any quotations in file

Sample csv file:

```
Name,Age,Year of Service,Membership,Audit,Leaves,CTC
Rob,'54',32,'Gold',N,5,"335000.50"
```

Code :

```
with open('output.csv','r') as i:
    for row in csv.reader(i):
        for columns in row:
            print(columns.replace('"',''))
```

above code will remove double quotes and print values without double quotes.
i also need to remove single quote as well.

Request your help on this

Comment: `Replace("'","")` doesn't work?

Comment: @FiddlingBits...I am trying for single line so double quotes and single quotes will neglected.In your case single quotes only we can handle

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string

Comment: Why don't you just do this in a text editor?  It's two commands in vim.  Are you sure none of the fields has embedded quote marks?

Answer (score 1):

Use `strip()`.

```
with open('output.csv','r') as i:
  for row in csv.reader(i):
     for columns in row:
        print(columns.replace('"','').strip("'"))

Rob
54
32
Gold
N
5
335000.50
```