# Python Best Way to Delete matches?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to delete multiple strings from a phrase in python.
For example I want to delete: `apple, orange, tomato`

How can I do that easily without writing 10 replaces like this:

```
str = str.replace('apple','').replace(....).replace(....)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace multiple substrings of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you are repeating yourself, think of a loop instead.

```
for word in ('apple','cherry','tomato','grape'):
    str = str.replace(word,'')
```

And, by the way, `str` is a poor name for a variable, since it's the name of a type.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use *re.sub* and list the words in a group between word boundaries `\b`

```
import re

s = re.sub(r"\b(?:apple|orange|tomato)\b", "", s)
```