# Replace operation inside a Python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

my code below works fine.

```
import re

def mycontent(text: str):
    netx = text
    urls = re.findall("MyText", netx)
    for i in urls:
        netx = netx.replace(i, "MyReplaceText")
    
    return netx
```

I want to combine this word with a few more words. How can I do that? Thank you.

```
import re

def mycontent(text: str):
    netx = text
    urls = re.findall("MyText", "MyText1" tnetx)
    for i in urls:
        netx = netx.replace(i, "MyReplaceText", "MyText1Replace"")

    return netx
```

I tried in the form but I couldn't get results, it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide expected and actual output.

Comment: Just put all the words in a single string (`"MyReplaceTextMyReplaceText"`). If that's not what you mean, please clarify.

Comment: Yes, I want change to show all words in one array. Thank u.

Comment: Your code does not compile. `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)` takes only one `pattern` parameter. You should construct a regular expression for your pattern.

Comment: Why are you using the loop instead of `re.sub()` to replace all the regexp matches?

Comment: don't use `re`, just have a list of tuple pairs of find and replace strings, and loop through those applying `.replace(find_str, replace_str)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/6116978/6045800

Answer (score 0):

To match multiple strings, use alternatives in the regexp. Then use `re.sub()` with a replacement function that looks up the corresponding replacement.

```
def mycontent(text: str) -> str:
    replacements = {'MyText': 'MyReplacement1', 'MyText1', 'MyReplacement1'}
    return re.sub(r'MyText|MyText1', lambda m: replacements[m.group(), text]
```