# Replacing letters with other letters in a case-sensitive way

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to replace specific letters with other specific letters, so here's an example of a desired output and input:

Input: `QWe RtYy`
Output: `ABc DeFf`

I tried using `string.replace` but I realized that it would be very long for each uppercase and lowercase letter and what I tried didn't work properly, because only the last letter would change.

Extract of my code:

```
string = input("Enter text.\n")

NewString = string.replace("q", "a")
NewString = string.replace("Q", "A")
NewString = string.replace("w", "b")
NewString = string.replace("W", "B")

print(NewString)
```

But when I write `"q Q w W"` I get `"q Q w B"` instead of `"a A b B"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may wish to use `str.translate` to effect this change, as shown below in a simple example.

```
>>> d = str.maketrans({'q': 'a', 'Q': 'A'})
>>> "qQ".translate(d)
'aA'
```

You could also use the `re` module to accomplish this with regular expressions. This approach lets us replace multicharacter substrings.

```
>>> import re
>>> d = {'He': 'l', 'l': 'o'}
>>> s = 'Hello'
>>> r = re.compile(rf"{'|'.join(d.keys())}")
>>> r.sub(lambda m: d[m[0]], s)
'looo'
```

If we tried to accomplish this with repeated calls to `str.replace` as you have *almost* gotten right*, we might see unintended side-effects as the replace will be taking place on the entire transformed string, including the parts that have *already been replaced*.

```
>>> s = 'Hello'
>>> s = s.replace('He', 'l')
>>> s = s.replace('l', 'o')
>>> s
'oooo'
```

* You simply needed to reassign the results of the string replacement back to the same `string` variable so that all of the replacements take effect.

Comment: Why was their code not working?

Comment: Added clarification on that.

Answer (score 1):

You only see the last change because `NewString` is being overwritten each time - but using the *original* `string`. You can instead change each `NewString` with `.replace` like this:

```py
string = input("Enter text.\n")

NewString = string.replace("q", "a")
NewString = NewString.replace("Q", "A")
NewString = NewString.replace("w", "b")
NewString = NewString.replace("W", "B")

print(NewString)
```

Also [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string) for some efficient ways to replace multiple substrings instead of doing it like this.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing with the case sensitivity is just fine. You just have to assign the `NewString` a different way--- by doing `NewString = string.replace("some", "thing")`, you are changing the value of `NewString`, but from the *original* text (i.e. your input). So, the only thing that will change is the *last* character. Instead, you should redefine from your *new* variable:

```
string = input("Enter text.\n")

NewString = string.replace("q", "a")
NewString = NewString.replace("Q", "A")
NewString = NewString.replace("w", "b")
NewString = NewString.replace("W", "B")
```

For versatility, you can use `str.split()` to split items by whitespace.

```
string = input("Enter text.\n")

NewString = string.replace(string.split()[0], "a")
NewString = NewString.replace(string.split()[1], "A")
NewString = NewString.replace(string.split()[2], "b")
NewString = NewString.replace(string.split()[3], "B")
```

Or, in one line (excluding input):

```
string = input("Enter text.\n")

NewString = string.replace(string.split()[0], "a").replace(string.split()[1], "A").replace(string.split()[2], "b").replace(string.split()[3], "B")
```

Hope this helps.